# Parsing another JSON Format

Tags: java, android

So here's the following code :

```
        jObj = new JSONObject(valeurARenvoyer);
        hauteur = jObj.getString("niveauEau");
        debit = jObj.getString("debit");
        date = jObj.getString("dateReleve");
        batterie = jObj.getString("chargeBatterie");
        presence = jObj.getString("etatPerimetrique");
        bat = jObj.getString("chargeBatterie");
```

So i used this code to parse a JSON which was like that :

```
{"id":"15","id_Station":"Artiguelouve","Date_Releve":"2017-02-16 16:07:41","Niveau_Eau":"29","Charge_Batterie":"9","Etat_Perimetrique":"0","Debit":"13.35"}
```

It worked well, but now my JSON response looks like that :

```
{"Station":"Artiguelouve","debit":[{"niveauEau":0,"debit":32.5,"dateReleve":{"date":"2017-06-08 15:59:03","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"},"idStation":"Artiguelouve","etatPerimetrique":true,"chargeBatterie":14590}]}
```

With this response i can't find how to parse this.
valeurARenvoyer is my JSON. Can you have any solution to do that please ?

Comment: `i can't find how to parse this` what have you tried? Which errors happen? Please note that `please somebody, give me a code to parse this JOSN because I don't want to spend my time on it` can't be treated as a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code to get response

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);//put your json response
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            String station = jsonObject.getString("Station");
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("debit");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {

                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int niveauEau = jsonObject1.getInt("niveauEau");
                int debit = jsonObject1.getInt("debit");
                String isStation = jsonObject1.getString("idStation");
                boolean etatPerimetrique = jsonObject1.getBoolean("etatPerimetrique");
                int chargeBatterie = jsonObject1.getInt("chargeBatterie");

                JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("dateReleve");

                String date = jsonObject2.getString("date");
                int timezone_type = jsonObject2.getInt("timezone_type");
                String timezone = jsonObject2.getString("timezone");

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
        try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(valeurARenvoyer);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("debit");

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            // you can get niveauEau, debit, idStation, etatPerimetrique,
            // chargeBatterie, dateReleve JsonObject values in this loop
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```